# Odoo custom addons path not included when refreshing list

Tags: git, odoo, add-on, odoo-13

I have installed odoo v13.0 on Debian 10 with the script found [there](https://github.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript/tree/13.0)

The conf file with addons path is the following :

```
[options] 
; This is the password that allows database operations:
admin_passwd = XXXXXX
xmlrpc_port = 8069
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
addons_path = /odoo/odoo-server/addons, /odoo/custom/addons, /odoo/custom/OCA/reporting-engine
```

/odoo/custom/OCA is a path where I clone some git repositories from OCA github account, https://github.com/OCA/reporting-engine in my example, so /odoo/custom/OCA/reporting-engine is filled with all the OCA modules for V13.0 :

```
root@Odoo:/odoo/custom/OCA# ls -l reporting-engine/
total 124
-rw-r--r--  1 odoo odoo 34503 Apr 13 09:37 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 odoo odoo  1398 Apr 13 09:37 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 10 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 09:37 base_comment_template
drwxr-xr-x 10 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 09:37 bi_sql_editor
drwxr-xr-x 12 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 09:37 kpi_dashboard
-rw-r--r--  1 odoo odoo    13 Apr 13 09:37 oca_dependencies.txt
drwxr-xr-x  9 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 09:37 report_batch
drwxr-xr-x 10 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 09:37 report_context
drwxr-xr-x 11 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 09:37 report_csv
drwxr-xr-x  9 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 09:37 report_layout_config
drwxr-xr-x 12 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 10:25 report_py3o
drwxr-xr-x 10 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 09:37 report_py3o_fusion_server
drwxr-xr-x  8 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 09:37 report_qr
drwxr-xr-x  6 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 09:37 report_qweb_element_page_visibility
drwxr-xr-x  8 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 09:37 report_qweb_parameter
drwxr-xr-x  6 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 09:37 report_qweb_pdf_fixed_column
drwxr-xr-x  9 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 09:37 report_qweb_pdf_watermark
drwxr-xr-x  9 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 09:37 report_wkhtmltopdf_param
drwxr-xr-x 11 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 09:37 report_xlsx
drwxr-xr-x  9 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 09:37 report_xlsx_helper
drwxr-xr-x 11 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 09:37 report_xml
-rw-r--r--  1 odoo odoo    39 Apr 13 09:37 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x 21 odoo odoo  4096 Apr 13 09:37 setup
```

After the clone, I have changed the owner to the odoo user as shown in the above list.
I have added the path in custom addons section in the conf file.
I have restarted the service odoo to take into account the new path.
I have refreshed the module list in the odoo configuration web page.

And no new modules are found !

```
2021-04-14 13:04:50,869 27535 INFO ? odoo.service.server: Hit CTRL-C again or send a second signal to force the shutdown.
2021-04-14 13:04:50,869 27535 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: current thread: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140669907216192)>
2021-04-14 13:04:50,869 27535 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: process <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140669907216192)> (False)
2021-04-14 13:04:50,870 27535 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: process <Thread(odoo.service.cron.cron0, started daemon 140669762197248)> (True)
2021-04-14 13:04:50,870 27535 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: process <Thread(odoo.service.cron.cron1, started daemon 140669770852096)> (True)
2021-04-14 13:04:50,870 27535 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: --
2021-04-14 13:04:51,430 27747 DEBUG ? odoo.netsvc: logger level set: "odoo.http.rpc.request:INFO"
2021-04-14 13:04:51,430 27747 DEBUG ? odoo.netsvc: logger level set: "odoo.http.rpc.response:INFO"
2021-04-14 13:04:51,430 27747 DEBUG ? odoo.netsvc: logger level set: ":INFO"
2021-04-14 13:04:51,430 27747 DEBUG ? odoo.netsvc: logger level set: "odoo:DEBUG"
2021-04-14 13:04:51,430 27747 DEBUG ? odoo.netsvc: logger level set: "odoo.sql_db:INFO"
2021-04-14 13:04:51,431 27747 DEBUG ? odoo.netsvc: logger level set: ":DEBUG"
2021-04-14 13:04:51,431 27747 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 13.0
2021-04-14 13:04:51,431 27747 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /etc/odoo-server.conf
2021-04-14 13:04:51,431 27747 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons', '/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/13.0', '/odoo/odoo-server/addons', '/odoo/custom/addons', '/odoo/custom/OCA/reporting-engine']
2021-04-14 13:04:51,431 27747 INFO ? odoo: database: default@default:default
2021-04-14 13:04:51,569 27747 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
2021-04-14 13:04:51,683 27747 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: Setting signal handlers
2021-04-14 13:04:51,687 27747 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: cron0 started!
2021-04-14 13:04:51,687 27747 DEBUG ? odoo.service.server: cron1 started!
2021-04-14 13:05:07,368 6506 INFO test2 werkzeug: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [14/Apr/2021 13:05:07] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 - 8 0.002 50.010
```

I tried to add a symlink of a module directory in /odoo/custom/OCA/reporting-engine to /odoo/custom/addons, and the new module has been found after restarting the server and refreshing the modules list...

```
root@Odoo:/odoo/custom# ls -l addons/
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 odoo odoo 41 Apr 13 10:54 account_payment_mode -> ../OCA/bank-payment/account_payment_mode/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 odoo odoo 44 Apr 13 10:53 account_payment_partner -> ../OCA/bank-payment/account_payment_partner/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 odoo odoo 50 Apr 13 10:42 base_company_extension -> ../akretion/odoo-usability/base_company_extension/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 odoo odoo 42 Apr 13 10:43 base_usability -> ../akretion/odoo-usability/base_usability/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 odoo odoo 53 Apr 13 10:50 purchase_commercial_partner -> ../OCA/purchase-workflow/purchase_commercial_partner/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 odoo odoo 60 Apr 13 10:32 purchase_report_py3o -> ../akretion/odoo-py3o-report-templates/purchase_report_py3o/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 odoo odoo 46 Apr 13 10:43 purchase_usability -> ../akretion/odoo-usability/purchase_usability/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 odoo odoo 35 Apr 13 10:24 report_py3o -> ../OCA/reporting-engine/report_py3o
lrwxrwxrwx 1 odoo odoo 50 Apr 13 10:24 report_py3o_fusion_server -> ../OCA/reporting-engine/report_py3o_fusion_server/
```

So /odoo/custom/OCA/reporting-engine/moduleDirectory is not working, but /odoo/custom/addons/moduleDirectory is working...

Since there are some dependencies, I don't want to add them all manually, what's the difference between those directories?

I have the same problem with other git clones like https://github.com/akretion/odoo-py3o-report-templates.git

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Give Absolute path of addons it may solve your issue!!!